# How to set the corner radius of a UIContextualAction?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, uicontextualaction

I haven't found anything on how to do this so I am asking a question.

I made a cell with three actions:

1. A check action,
2. an edit action,
3. and a delete action.

The only problem is that my cell has a corner radius to it and I want my actions to also have a corner radius. How do I set the corner radius of a UIContextualAction?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `UIContextualAction` inherits from `NSObject`, there's no layer to draw or adjust. You'll have to build your own utility underlay view and swipe gesture, or use something like [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit) which supports custom styled contextual actions.

Comment: You can also use UIPanGestureRecognizer to make your own swipe view. And under your view you can put any view.